# Laravel 6 language translation issue, error message cannot be translated properly

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-6

Hello I have set my laravel 6 language session variable as, 'sentence'

so I display my texts as `<p>{{ __('sentence.Change Password') }}</p>`

But now I'm trying to display one of my error message which is generated from the controller in the front end blade,

my error message and redirect code as follows

```
return redirect()->route('login')
                ->withFail('{{ __(sentence.Sorry Invalid Credentials) }}','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
```

But this message is not translating properly. In the front end also it shows, {{ __(sentence.Sorry Invalid Credentials) }}

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
return redirect()->route('login')
                ->withFail(__('sentence.Sorry Invalid Credentials'),'Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
```

Comment: nope, now it showing as, __(sentence.Sorry Invalid Credentials)

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev Just made a change to my answer

Comment: Marking it as an answer would be greatly appreciated :D